# Find an analytic function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f'(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ or show that no such function exists.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a guess that the function does not exist. But I dont know how to show it.
I have been suggested to look at the following theorems:

1): If f is entire, then f is everywhere the derivative of an analytic function. That is there exists an entire F such that $F'(z)=f(z)$  $\forall z$.

2): If f is entire and if C is a (smooth) closed curve, $\int_C f(z) dz=0$.

I hope you can help.

Comment: **Hint**: $z=z+1-1$

Comment: Something that does the job here is the fundamental theorem of calculus (for complex functions) : $\int_{\gamma} f'(z) dz = f(\text{end pt}) - f(\text{start pt})$. So for closed curves $\gamma$ we get $\int_{\gamma} f'(z) dz = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint.** Compute the following:
$$
\int_{|z+1|=1}\frac{z}{z+1}\,dz.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Formally, one has $f(z) = \int \frac{z}{z+1} dz = \int ( 1 - \frac{1}{z+1} ) dz = z - \log (1+z) + \mathcal{C}$, so the issue is with $\log(1+z)$ being multivalued on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{-1\}$. Here is how one can show that there does not exists $f$ on $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ such that $\, f'(z)= \frac{1}{z}$. Assume such $f$ exists. Then the function $\frac{\exp f(z)}{z}$ has zero derivative on $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ and so $\frac{\exp(f(z))}{z} \equiv $ const , and so $\frac{\exp(f(-z))}{\exp(f(z)} =\frac{-z}{z}\equiv -1$, and by continuity and connectednes, $\, f(-z) - f(z) \equiv (2k+1) \, \pi i$ for some integer $k$. Now plug in  $-z$ instead of $z$ $\ldots$

Comment: This is in fact a discrete analogue of the integration along a circle.